# Once i have written the css code and included dz sections with php includes, the styles i make no longer affect the style.css file

Tags: php, css

I have used includes in Php to create a template system where I can reuse in a prototype website I'm making. But after this when I try to add additional styles in the CSS file it has no effect.

I even comment out my entire `style.CSS` file, and the styling I made did 
 affect the site, its like the `style.CSS` is no taking effect on the web page:

```
includes/aside.php
```

`CSS/style.CSS` dose not affect the initial styling I made in `aside.php` before using includes.

I expected the new styles I made in `style.CSS` to affect my included `aside.php` tag, but no output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is usually caused by cache, pls try to clear the browser cache and the server cache.